# How to save object to react context API?

Tags: reactjs, react-context

I am new to React and I am building a online store website. I use context API to store my products list that fetch from database. But "Objects are not valid as a React child" error will appear when I try to set it as object. Below are my codes,

ProductsContext.jsx

```
import { createContext,useContext,useEffect,useState } from "react";

export const ProductsContext = createContext(null);

export const Products = () => {
    return useContext(ProductsContext)
  }
  
export const ProductsProvider = ({children}) => {
    const [contextProducts, setProducts] = useState()
    

    const contextValue = { contextProducts, setProducts};

    return (
      <ProductsContext.Provider value={contextValue} displayName="Products Context"> 
        {children}
      </ProductsContext.Provider>
    )
}
```

api.js

```
export async function GETProductsListByCat(cat) {

    const command = new QueryCommand({
        TableName: 'mytable',
        IndexName: 'category',
        KeyConditionExpression: 'cat = :cat',
        ExpressionAttributeValues: {
            ':cat': cat,
        },
    });
    try {
        const response = await docClient.send(command);
        const products_awsFormat = response.Items;
        const products_transformedData = {};
        for (const item of products_awsFormat) {
            products_transformedData[item.productId] = {
                ...item,
            };
        }
        console.log(products_transformedData); //see below picture
        return products_transformedData;
    } catch (e) {}

}
```

Products.jsx

```
import { useState, useEffect, useContext } from 'react';
import { ProductsContext } from '../../contextAPI/ProductsContext';
import { GETProductsListByCat } from "../../src/server/api"

function Products() {
    const { contextProducts, setProducts } = useContext(ProductsContext);
    useEffect(() => {

        if (!contextProducts||contextProducts.length ===0) {
            async function fetchData() {
                try {
                    const productList = await GETProductsListByCat("cate");
                    setProducts(productList);
                } catch (error) {
                    console.error('Error fetching data:', error);
                }
            }
            fetchData();
        }
        }, []);


    return (
           ...
            {contextProducts&&
                <div>
                  {Object.keys(contextProducts).map((cookieId) => (
                        <a href={`cookies/${cookieId}`} className='product-container' key={cookieId}>
                            <img src="products/01/thumbnail.jpg" alt="product" className='product-thumbnail'></img>
                            <div className='label'> {contextProducts[cookieId].name}</div>
                            <div className='label'>${contextProducts[cookieId].price}/100g</div>
                        </a>
                    ))}
                </div>
            }
    );
}

export default Products;
```

[image]
I am getting "Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead." with the current code.

Comment: I want to see code in `{Object.keys(contextProducts).map(...)}`

Comment: @Adrid added code. I tried to comment out ``{Object.keys(contextProducts).map(...)}`` part and the error still there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not initialized contextProducts with an initial value. This can cause issues when contextProducts is used before data is fetched. It's generally a good practice to initialize state with a default value that matches the expected data type. Since you're dealing with a list of products, you might want to initialize it as an empty object:

```
const [contextProducts, setProducts] = useState({});
```

Answer (score 2):

Inside Products.jsx

you should not return object what you did is you trying to return object instead of jsx markup

Don't:
return ({})

Do:

```
function Products() {
const { contextProducts, setProducts } =useContext(ProductsContext);
useEffect(() => {

    if (!contextProducts||contextProducts.length ===0) {
        async function fetchData() {
            try {
                const productList = await GETProductsListByCat("cate");
                setProducts(productList);
            } catch (error) {
                console.error('Error fetching data:', error);
            }
        }
        fetchData();
    }
    }, []);


return (contextProducts&&
            <div>
              {Object.keys(contextProducts).map((cookieId) => (
                    <a href={`cookies/${cookieId}`} className='product-container' key={cookieId}>
                        <img src="products/01/thumbnail.jpg" alt="product" className='product-thumbnail'></img>
                        <div className='label'> {contextProducts[cookieId].name}</div>
                        <div className='label'>${contextProducts[cookieId].price}/100g</div>
                    </a>
                ))}
            </div>||null
        
);
```

}

export default Products;